# Is there a way to know whether or not something is added to localStorage?

Tags: javascript

I want to have a button that toggles something in and out of localStorage (it's clicked once and it adds something to localStorage, it's clicked again and that something disappears from localStorage). I want to do something like the code below, but toggling "status" instead of setting it permanently.

Comment: "I want to do something like the code below" ... where?

Comment: _"Is there a way to know whether or not something is added to localStorage?"_ - you try to read it _from_ localStorage, and see what you get back ...?

Comment: Call `localStorage.getItem()`. If it returns `null`, nothing is stored at that name.

Comment: Try reading it back, if you get something then it's there... otherwise, not!!!

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I don't know I got you or not. Here is a solution..

First I'm taking a button :

```
<button>Toggle</button>
```

Then using some scripts to toggle (add, remove) the item inside of localsotrage.

```
<script>
const button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  const item = localStorage.getItem('info');
  if (!item){
    localStorage.setItem('info', 'Hello World')
  }else{
    localStorage.removeItem('info')
  }
})
</script>
```

inside of this script simple method has been implemented. At first I'm taking a value from localstorage. Inside of if/else condition when `item` value if falsy it will add item into localstorage. When it is truthy it will remove from localStorage.